# ERROR: PC register is not available when starts debugging C/C++ programs on Visual Studio Code MinGw

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, debugging, mingw

I followed these instructions:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw

But, when I try debugging (F5), it shows this kind of error on the bottom of the Debug Console and never starts to debug.

I searched on Google, but I can't find the solution.

The previous steps worked out.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Screenshot attached:
[ERROR: PC register is not available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVSuT.png)

The MinGW tools are in my PATH:
[My PATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5saG.png)

I tested the g++ and the gdb with --version on the console:
[The MinGW tools are correctly installed and available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGp7F.png)

I share my configuration .json files:
[Configuration files](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvVQXnTnECKpgxV32iLeUDqyx1xq?e=AAB0KI)

Comment: Did the previous steps from the instructions work out?1) Are the MinGW tools found in your PATH? 2) Did you succeed in building helloworld.cpp? 3) It would be helpful, if you share your task.json and launch.json configuration files.

Comment: Yeah, the previous steps worked out. 1)The MinGW tools are in my PATH (screenshot). 2) Yes, the compiler built the helloworld.cpp 3) The files are attached. 
Thanks. @MiguelG.